# Working with textarea

Tags: textarea, watin

How can I work with textareas using watin? There is no function like "browser.TextArea(...)".

Is there another name for textareas? I only need to find it and work with rows/cols.

Comment: I don't think WatiN provides support for interacting with the values of the 'rows' or 'cols' attributes.

Comment: You might want to pass a link or post some DOM content, so that others can have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Use the TextField method to access a TextArea.

From the [Watin Homepage](http://watin.org/) (modified for this question)

```
[Test] 
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
  using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
  {
    // If there was a TextArea with the name q - the next line would get the TextArea object and assign it to the textField variable.
    var textField = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")); 
   // Do what you need to do with the TextArea, for example, get the text from the textArea:
   string textAreaText = textField.Value;
  }
}
```

Comment: how? i have to search the textarea like a textfield? And when i have the textarea in the textfield, what i have to do? Thanks

Comment: thanks for the advertisement. Otherwise, the solution isnt working. The value is like empty "". The textarea is in a div. What can i do? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this myself.  I thought I would post a more complete answer for people that are still stumped by this.  Just use the GetAttributeValue method on the TextField instance like so:

```
TextField field = Document.TextField(Find.ByName("comments"));
Assert.AreEqual("10", field.GetAttributeValue("rows"));
Assert.AreEqual("42", field.GetAttributeValue("cols"));
```